# Edit queue empty but there is one pending edit — Une modification est proposée et pourtant la queue est vide

Tags: support, suggested-edits

D'après la barre de notification en haut du site (pour les utilisateurs ayant 2000 rep), il y a une modification proposée. Pourtant, quand je clique sur le ➀, la queue est vide.

---

Hopes this [support](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) post will get the attention of SE staff, so they can investigate. I tried to reach Rebecca on the chat, but she didn't respond yet.

There seems to be a problem with the “suggested edits” queue on the main site. When I log onto the site, I get the badge indicating that there is one edit to be reviewed:

[image]

When I click on it, however, the edit queue is empty:

[image]

This is not a “temporary” problem, as it has persisted for the last two days. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sorry I missed your chat @lert.)

Do you know if you had a pending edit that you had submitted?  Without checking the code, I would guess that perhaps there was 1 edit in the queue that you had submitted.  Since you can't approve it, it doesn't show it to you.

The queue is empty now, do you still see a number?

Comment: Probably that was it, it's now cleared. Thanks!

Comment: I've exactly the same problem now, and I can confirm that the two pending edits are mine

Comment: The problem is still there… There's one of my pending wiki edits in the queue, but it won't show up in the suggested edits list.

Comment: Maybe this should be classified as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify [Rebecca's answer](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/edit-queue-seems-to-have-issues/109#109): if you have less than [4000](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) reputation, your suggested tag edits go into the queue since they need to be approved by another user (with at least [1500](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) reputation). If you have at least [2000](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) reputation, you see the total number of pending suggested edits. By the time you see have access to the suggested edit queue, you can approve all edits except the ones you submitted (which in practice can only happen with tag wikis): those won't even appear in the queue. If your [quota](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81051/out-of-votes-change-message/103382#103382) is exceeded (unlikely outside Stack Overflow, unless one user goes on a large spate of edits, typically on tag wikis), you'll see edits in the queue that you won't be able to approve until the next day.

---

En dessous de [4000](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) points de réputation, les modifications proposées aux wikis d'étiquette sont placées dans une queue en attendant d'être approuvées par un autre utilisateur (qui doit avoir au moins [1500](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) points de réputation)).

Si votre réputation est d'au moins [2000](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools), le nombre total de modifications proposées apparaît dans la barre du haut du site. Ce nombre inclut les modifications que vous avez vous-même proposées, qui n'apparaissent pas quand vous visionnez la queue ; en pratique, ceci ne peut arriver qu'avec des modifications proposées sur les wikis d'étiquette.

Il peut arriver aussi que des modifications apparaissent dans la queue mais que vous ne puissiez pas voter pour ou contre, si votre [quota](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81051/out-of-votes-change-message/103382#103382) est dépassé pour la journée (dans ce cas, vous pourrez voter demain). Ceci arrive très rarement en dehors de Stack Overflow, essentiellement lorsqu'un utilisateur propose beaucoup de nouveaux wikis d'étiquette.